# Customizing youtube player view in android

Tags: android, youtube-api

i am using an youtube player api of google to play youtube videos, it specifies three different styles of player view, is this any way to customize the player view in android.

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**I don't know what kind of style you want, but you can use YouTube Player as Activity or Fragment or a View.**

**So you can basically customise your player easily with new YouTubePlayer API**

If you want some simple youtube player with fullscreen (no titlebar mode), You are welcome to use my code!!

This source handle "**Orientation Problem**", "**Media Volume Problem**", "**Youtube Url Parsing Problem**"

1. Here is open source library

   https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/SimpleYouTubePlayer
2. This is sample codes

   https://gist.github.com/TheFinestArtist/5545437
3. I also made sample app you can download

   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thefinestartist.simpleyoutubeplayer

Comment: i want to show youtube videos in recyclerview  and play it individually one at a time within those bounds.any example.

Answer (score 5):

Try this link for youtube video play in my layout : http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/using-googles-youtube-api-in-your-android-apps/

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    static private final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "add your own key here!";
    static private final String VIDEO = "4SK0cUNMnMM";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView)
        findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
        YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Oh no! "+error.toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
        boolean wasRestored) {
        player.loadVideo(VIDEO);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I did not downvote, it's great you edited the answer to include relevant details from the link :)

Answer (score 3):

You can pick he chromeless style, it doesn't have any controls - it's only a rectangle that plays a video under programmatic control.

You're free to implement your own controls UI outside the player and wire them up through the YouTubePlayer that you get back after initializing a YouTubePlayerView or YouTubePlayerFragment. Keep in mind that, as mentioned in the YouTubePlayerView JavaDoc, "it is not permitted to overlay the [player] view with other views while a video is playing"

Comment: is it possible to customize actionbar to include media controls like progressbar and other buttons?

Comment: You are the one! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

FYI: you can use PopupWindow to workaround restriction: "it is not permitted to overlay the [player] view with other views while a video is playing"